# How to correctly combine find, sed & tr to replace a newline in all my files

Tags: bash, sed, tr

All of my PHP files currently start

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
```

It's a minor thing, but I'd like to change them all to

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
```

I think I need to use tr as sed works on a single line at a time.  But I can't come up with the right command to recursively do this through a directory of .php files.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you required to only use sed and tr? This would be easy in perl.

Comment: Not at all - perl's ok if that's a better tool for the job.  I've never used it though, so be clear for me :)

Comment: if its only the first line everytime you could do `sed '1N;s/\n//' *`

Comment: `tr` will mangle all newlines in the file, not just the first.  It is almost certainly the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: If the `<?php` line isn't the first, you can adapt what @123 said to: `sed '/<?php$/{ 1N; s/\n/ /; }'` to look for as-yet-unchanged `<?php` lines and fix them.

Comment: or use perl `perl -pe 'chomp if /<\?php$/'`

Comment: That did the trick @123, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that out with GNU sed:

```
find . -name *.php -exec sed -i '1{N;s/<?php\s*\n\s*declare/<?php declare/}' {} \;
```

The `find` bit retrieves all .php files in the current directory, the `sed` bit edits them in-place to change a matched two-line definition into a one-line definition.

It assumes the php opening tag is in the first line, and looks for a second line starting with declare (and optional spaces).

---

If you don't use GNU sed, this command should be posix compliant :

`find . -name *.php -exec sed -i.bak '1{N;s/<?php[[:space:]]*\`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`[[:space:]]*declare/<?php declare/}' {} \;`

However it also creates backups of the .php files, which can be removed once sure of the success of the command with an additional find :

```
find . -name *.php.bak -delete
```

Comment: Note this is GNU sed only .

Comment: @123 thanks for the info ; could you tell me where I divert from posix sed? I'd love to edit the answer to make it portable.

Comment: The -i flag without an arg is gnu only and im also pretty sure escaped character classes are as well. [[:space:]] is portable

Comment: @123 I'm afraid this is not the only problem, when adding the `--posix` flag to my GNU sed call, no matching happens (regardless of the -i flag). I'll try to pinpoint what is GNU specific but in the meantime I've edited my question to indicate it's specific to GNU sed.

Comment: it will be the character classes i.e `\s` try `[[:space:]]`. Also note that --posix, doesn't actually guarantee posix compliance. I can't remember what it was but i used it a while ago and there was something that worked with that flag but not actual on a BSD system.

Comment: @123 a script can be POSIX compliant without working the same on 2 different versions of the same tool because, among other things, POSIX allows for undefined behavior which is up to the tool developer to implement as they choose (e.g. `{print > "foo" "bar"}` in awk). So `--posix` probably does guarantee POSIX compliance, it just doesn't guarantee that the script will work the same in a different, but also POSIX-compliant, version of the same tool.

Comment: @Aaron use of `\n` to represent a newline is an example of something non-portable in your script. The portable way to have a newline in `sed` is a backslash followed by a literal newline.If the script works I'd say don't worry about that but if it doesn't then that's something to look at.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the info. Most people will probably use the GNU answer anyway so I might as well make the portable one right !